# How can I find a set of coordinates relative to a rotation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I find a position relative to a point that has been rotated? The idea is, that I'm rotating an entity at a certain position, and need to be able to find a position relative to that entity's rotation, such that 10 units above the entity relative to its rotation is different from 10 units *directly* above the entity. Hopefully this diagram should give you an idea of what I mean:

[image]

Note: I'm doing this in the `<canvas>` tag with pure Javascript.

Also note: I'm only just finishing Algebra, and have done just a little trigonometry and some geometry, so please make your explanation relatively clear. Sin, cos, and tangent are only just beginning to make sense, and I had to look up the concept of radians myself the other day in order to work with `<canvas>`'s rotation function (thanks, Wikipedia!).

Also also note: I have tried looking this up myself (Google, SO, elsewhere), but not knowing the proper terms, I wasn't able to find anything. I'm sure this must be fairly simple, but it may as well be Greek to me.

Comment: Your description isn't clear - rotation happens around an axis/point. It's unclear what your axis is here. Is each square rotated around the origin? Or around its own centre? Also, 45 degrees isn't a good example, because it looks like it could be from either side. Which brings me to my final point - rotation is directional, you don't make it clear what direction the rotation is in.

Comment: Ah, the axis would be the center of the square. Oh, okay. Well, maybe 35 degrees would serve to explain my point. I thought I made it clear that I rotated the square 45 degrees to the right with my diagram, no? I guess it's pretty clear that I'm unfamiliar with working with rotations. :)

Comment: Not really, since 45 degrees "right" from the y-axis can be 45 degrees "left" from the x-axis, which is why choosing a smaller angle would be better.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, I'll change my diagram--thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a point that is `d` units from a point `(x,y)` at an angle `θ`, where the angle is taken relative to the point as its origin, in the clockwise direction, from the positive y-axis, the point is given by `(x + d*cos(π/2-θ), y + d*sin(π/2-θ))`

Comment: I believe this is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you kow how to rotate the square, you know howto rotate the vector.
What you did with the `square (25,25)`, do with the `vector(25,15)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with vectors and matrices.Let's say that the direction to the 25,10 is forward vector of your cube.So you can apply the rotation matrix to this vector ,that is multiplying this vector by rotation matrix which is rotated amount of degrees you need.That will return you your relative position.Hope it is clear.I am not JavaScript expert.But I am sure there is some Vector math API out there you can use.
You have to do these steps:

Calculate the vector from cubes position to your desired offset before the rotation.

Calculate rotation matrix with some rotation.

Multiply that vector by the rotation matrix to get the new rotated vector.

I found [this](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/api/matrix.html)          JavaScript Vector math lib.Take a look at the Matrix object.It has a method for vector multiplication.

Comment: You forgot the final step of translation.

Comment: How do I multiply the vector by the rotation matrix, exactly?

Comment: If he translates the cube then he can recalculate the forward vector using vector addition :)